# Could not find method jaxws() for arguments [com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4]

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb, gradle-plugin, wsimport

I am trying to generate java classes using following code but it's failing for some `gradle` plugin issue.

I searched for it and found there are many plugin available for generating the java classed from `xsd` but only few `plugins` for generating the code form `wsdl`.
`jaxb` is one of them which I thought to use.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
configurations {
    jaxws
}
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "2.1.4.RELEASE"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
        jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
} 

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'     
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    compile 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
} 

task wsimport {
    ext.destDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/generated")
    doLast {
        ant {
            sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.mkdirs()
            destDir.mkdirs()
            taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
                    classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                    classpath: configurations.jaxws.asPath
            )
            wsimport(keep: true,
                    destdir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
                    sourcedestdir: destDir,
                    extension: "true",
                    verbose: "false",
                    quiet: "false",
                    package: "com.abc.test",
                    xnocompile: "true",
                    wsdl: '${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdls/wsdl_1.0.0.wsdl') {
                xjcarg(value: "-XautoNameResolution")
            }
        }
    }
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn wsimport
    source wsimport.destDir
}
bootJar {
    baseName = 'API'
    version = '1.0'

}
```

Now here is the error I am getting when I try to build project using command line.

```
C:\DEV\workspace\API>gradlew clean build --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\DEV\workspace\API\build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'API'.
> Could not find method jaxws() for arguments [com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Taking reference from this code;
https://gist.github.com/ae6rt/8883335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
configurations {
    jaxws
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
    }
}
```

The configuration `jaxws` is not applicable for build script dependencies. First, it is placed outside of the `buildscript` configuration and thus not visible. Second, build script dependencies allow for `classpath` configuration only ([External dependencies for the build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies)). Removing `jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'` from the build script dependencies fixes issue

> Could not find method jaxws() for arguments [...]

Next issue is that you define the jax-ws dependency as

```
compile 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
```

and try to reference it as

```
taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
        classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
        classpath: configurations.jaxws.asPath)
                                  ^^^^^
```

The `jaxws` configuration has no dependencies defined so far, thus the path is empty. Changing the dependency in question to

```
jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
```

is likely to resolve this issue for you.

---

**Update**

Since Gradle replaced `File classesDir` with `FileCollection classesDirs`, as per your comment you're now receiving error

> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.mkdirs() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: min(), tails(), first(), inits(), minus(org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection), min(java.util.Comparator)

on line

```
sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.mkdirs()
```

If you've got only 1 classes output dir, a workaround would be to use

```
sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.singleFile.mkdirs()
```

(from: [FileCollection.getSingleFile()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#getSingleFile--))

Comment: Thanks,  Updated the build file as mentioned above. started getting a new error. Seems this is because I might be using some syntax which is not applicable in gradle 5.
Error:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':wsimport'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.mkdirs() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: min(), tails(), first(), inits(), minus(org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection), min(java.util.Comparator)

This is the error line:  sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.mkdirs()